# Panning a subview of UIScrollView after zooming in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have added a subview to a UIScrollView. When I zoom into the scroll view I want to pan around the subview.

In `touchesBegan:` I'm getting the initial location of the touch and then `touchesMoved:` I am able to determine how much to move the subview. It works perfectly when `zoomscale` is 1.0. However, when it is zoomed the pointer "breaks out" of the subview which it is intended to move (illustration here - pointer location is ilustrated as marquee tool).

The center of the view should be on pointer location, and not in it's current position! px and py variables ensure that wherever on the subview is clicked, while dragging it postion of the pointer always stays the same. [illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PELjB.png)

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    location.x = location.x * self.zoomScale;
    location.y = location.y * self.zoomScale;
    px = location.x;
    py = location.y;
    if ([touch view] == rotateView) {
        self.scrollEnabled = NO;
        return;
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self];
    location.x = location.x * self.zoomScale;
    location.y = location.y * self.zoomScale;
    if ([touch view] == rotateView) {
        rotateView.center = CGPointMake(rotateView.center.x + (location.x - px), rotateView.center.y + (location.y - py));
        px = location.x;
        py = location.y;
        return;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the approach you're taking, make the subview another UIScrollView and let it handle the panning.

(You may wish to set `scrollEnabled = NO` on your subview until zooming has occurred.)

Comment: I'm not sure that i understand completely what are you telling me. I should make all of my subviews another scrollviews? Hierarchy is like this: one scroll view(self) which contains another uiview which conatins elements which are able to move around in that uivew(and scrollview also beacuse scrollview contains uivew). (elements are a lot of uiimageviews or uiviews). Moving around works perfectly when scrollview is not zoomed in.

Comment: No, you should make the single view you mention ("I have added a subview to a UIScrollView") a scrollview. Or do you already have another scrollview as a subview of the scrollview you mention in your original question?

Comment: No, as i already stated in comment up there : I have UIScrollView. In it, i have container uiview which have a lot of uiimageviews or uiviews as subviews. I'm trying to move around those subviews(UIImageViews or UIviews) in container view. Is it more understandable now?
Are you sugesting that my "container" UIView should be UIScrollView? If i do that, no touches will be recognised by it's subviews - for my Parent scrollview i've created customscrollview class and overrided touches began, move and ends methods for recognizing touches on subviews.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that your container view should be a scrollview, and that your parent scrollview shouldn't override -touchesBegan: etc.

Comment: I still cannot come to a working solution. Here is what i have tried:
1)If my parent scroll view is UIScrolView, and my container UICustomScrollView, i'm not able to zoom in, because in - - (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1 container scrollview cannot be view for zooming.

Comment: For same reason both cannot be UICUstomSCrollViews.
2)if my container view is UIScrolview and my parent is UICustomScrolView, there's no detection of touches on subviews of container views.
I should mention that ovveride of touchesbegin,move and ends must exist(because, for example in touches moved there's a detection if two subviews of container view are intersecting).

Comment: if i understand things correctly, because i'm zooming in container UIView, i have somehow to transfer coordinates system from that view to parent UICustomScrollView when it is zoomed.

Comment: `-[UIView convertPoint:toView:]` and `-[UIView convertRect:toView:]` are what you need.

Comment: For some reason, that didn't work for me in any combination. But i manage to fix this, as i have noticed that coordinates are only changed in TouchesEnds, so i just multiplied them with zoomScale and it works now